# Programmatically created EditText's Input Type Password not working

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have created an `EditText` programmatically in `AlertDialog` but am not able to change its input type to password. Below is my code,

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final EditText edittext = new EditText(ChildMainScreen.this);
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
edittext.setSingleLine(true);
alert.setMessage("Please enter password to continue");
alert.setView(edittext);
alert.show();
```

I have also tried,

```
edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

and

```
edittext.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

But no luck.

Android version is 7 (Nougat)

Comment: Try both thing at same time check my answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `edittext.setSingleLine(true);` with `edittext.setMaxLines(1);`

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final EditText edittext = new EditText(ChildMainScreen.this);
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
edittext.setMaxLines(1);
alert.setMessage("Please enter password to continue");
alert.setView(edittext);
alert.show();
```

Comment: ohhhh... !! I firstly thought it is irrelevant but I gave it a try. And you are correct. It was happening because of `setSignleLine(true)`. It works with `setMaxLines(1)`. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try this-:

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);`
```

Instead of-:

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Tried. But still same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this:

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Comment: No use. Still same. :(

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

Try both thing at same time

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText edittext = new EditText(ChildMainScreen.this);
        edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        edittext.setSingleLine(true);
        edittext.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        alert.setMessage("Please enter password to continue");
        alert.setView(edittext);
        alert.show();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I had already tried, `setInputType` and `setTransformation` together, but after you said to try `setRawInputType` and `setTransformation` together. I just did, but not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below to get password as input

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final EditText edittext = new EditText(getActivity());
    edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD );
    edittext.setSingleLine(true);
    edittext.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    alert.setMessage("Please enter password to continue");
    alert.setView(edittext);
    alert.show();
```

as per the documentation

`TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` is entering a password, which should
 * be visible to the user.

`TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` is entering a password.

Answer (score 0):

first add this in your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

**And:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final EditText edittext = new EditText(ChildMainScreen.this);
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
edittext.setSingleLine(true);
edittext.setMaxLines(1);
alert.setMessage("Please enter password to continue");
alert.setView(edittext);
alert.show();
```

then check it gives you your desired behavior